# openmdao example optimization with parallelgroup

Tags: openmdao

Is there an example of an OpenMDAO optimization where each iteration of the optimization is designed to run in parallel? The examples I saw seemed focused on the design-of-experiment drivers.

Comment: could you clarify a bit? Do you mean, 10 processes to the root and letting it split them up to the various components?

Comment: @JustinGray For example, we have a wind farm model where we would like to run each directional case in parallel to calculate the annual energy production. I am curious about an example where the parallelization is split between groups, but my question is about implementing a group meant to run in parallel within an optimizer, like the wind farm example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you get into parallelism within the model, there are potentially many many different ways to split up a problem. However, the simplest case, and the one that is likely the most relevant to something like running multiple directional cases at the same time is just to use a multi-point like setup. This is done with a parallel group, as shown in the [multi-point doc.](http://openmdao.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/usr-guide/examples/parallel_multi_point.html#running-multi-point-in-parallel)

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't realize I could just specify a driver to turn this into an optimization problem.